# Detecting memory leaks with Visual studio 2010?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a wpf application that is leaking memory...is there a way to detect and fix these leaks using just visual studio without using any of the profiling tools? 
Or are there any free ones that I could use to detect and fix them?
Thaks

Comment: how did you know it is leaking memory ?

Comment: I run the application, open up a few windows with controls, close them ... the memory in the task manager just keeps up...I tried to programmitcally call GC.Collect()..at different points...that dosent clean up the controls...

Comment: Since .NET is managed it shouldn't leak - although you can't be sure when the GC will kick in

Comment: Be sure to call `Dispose` on any disposable objects. Also understand that explicitly calling `GC.Collect()` doesn't necessarily mean that the GC will run right then and there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Memory leaks in wpf C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6154810/memory-leaks-in-wpf-c-sharp)

Comment: I would avoid calling GC.Collect() also.  Let .net manage that for you.

Comment: Look at these SO question's for profiling tools and yes most of the tools have free trial period - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/399847/net-memory-profiling-tools and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312493/net-code-profiling-tools?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scitech's [memory profiler](http://memprofiler.com/) has a free trial period and is an excellent tool for investigating memory consumption issues.

Answer (score 1):

You can investigate memory leak only for application written in C++ in Visual Studio, take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x98tx3cf%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) at the official documentation ...

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5001873/142637) answer, which provides some links with useful information.

You'll basically need the [SOS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190764.aspx) debugger extension.